# Ubuntu 21.04 nohup python infinite loop stopped after several days

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, nohup

My python script is an infinite loop that does something every minutes. I use `time.sleep(x)` in the loop for 1 minute tic.

I use the following code to make it run in the background

```
nohup python3 -u main.py > output.log &
```

Every several days (around 3), it stopped, process didn't show up in

```
ps -ef | grep main.py
```

If it's OOM, output.log would have a line `Killed`, but output.log was totally normal.

Is it an Ubuntu feature that a process can only survive several days?

For your info, my ubuntu machine is a Google Cloud Compute VM with Ubuntu version 21.04

Comment: Frame challenge: why not a cron job?

Comment: Is there accidentally a related message in `dmesg`?

Comment: One possibility is that Google performed maintenance on your instance. That causes a reboot. If you need a program to run for long periods of time, convert the program to a service. That is fairly easy to do. Using nohup is the wrong approach.